# authentication version 12.10

Tags: password

I'm trying to sign in, log on, but I continually get a box saying password. Not recognized. I noticed in first boot up it mentioned password failed, shadow password would be used instead. I don't know what the shadow password is nor how to change it. I've been into user accounts and tried changing it that way but password is still not recognized.  My installation. Is installed in windows could and I can only log on as quest so I can't download. N install software. I am a new Ubuntu user, first time Linux user. Please. Help

Answer (score 0):

Here is a post that describes the shadow password process/algorithm (how you can figure out what the password is):

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=5318038

I hope it doesn't confuse you too much, but I couldn't find much else.